# Webi Rich Client Null pointer exception error

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, business-objects, webi

I'm trying to create a new Webi document based on a duplicate old one that we have been migrated from BOXI 3.1. I make my changes (filters, expressions) without any problem. When I save it (in different folders) and try to reopen it, I get the following error :

An error has occurred

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.sap.webi.ui.action.PageSizeAction.onUpdateUI(PageSizeAction.java:278)

And the document is damaged for good ! but I can open other documents.

**I'm on SAP BI 4.1 platform SP3, the server is on 4.1 but native version.**

I noticed that **.glf** is created before getting the error that has the following content :

> |527A5B9C76094BE390D9B582D003D7CE0|2016 01 27 11:25:58.876|+0000|Error| |>=|E| |TraceLog| 9504|  38|OpenDocTask-5515057-1| |0|0|0|0|-|-|-|-|-|-||||||||||com.sap.sl.sdk.parser.xml.ServerObjectParser||Unknown data type "error"
> |527A5B9C76094BE390D9B582D003D7CE1|2016 01 27 11:26:00.636|+0000|Error| |>=|E| |TraceLog| 9504|  38|OpenDocTask-5515057-1| ||||||||||||||||||||com.sap.webi.client.toolkit.document.DocumentInstanceWrapper||initRebeanNavigationState - getNavigationState
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: only START_TAG can have attributes END_DOCUMENT seen ...... @16:16

**ETC**

> |527A5B9C76094BE390D9B582D003D7CE2|2016 01 27 11:26:03.146|+0000|Error| |>=|E| |TraceLog| 9504|  16|AWT-EventQueue-0| ||||||||||||||||||||com.sap.webi.client.toolkit.document.DocumentInstanceWrapper||initRebeanNavigationState - getNavigationState
> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
> at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
> at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)

Please can anybody help me?

Thanks a lot,

Regards,
Adraa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your server and client should **always** be on the same version. Using a different version on the client than on the server is not supported.

The error message is referring to an error in the underlying XML representation of the Web Intelligence document.

You'll have to test if you can replicate the issue using the 4.1 version of the Web Intelligence Rich Client (so without any SP installed).